# Fusion Tables icon markers not showing with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I made a table with Fusion Tables of Google. I have a column to assign icon markers. When I use the embed code, the icons are showing correctly. But when I use the table ID and use the filters, all the icons turn to small red balls (the default icon).

How can I get customized icons from a column, without overloading the marker options styles? On the docs it says that I can only use 5 icon names.

Or how can I assign my own image for each filter I created on a column?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the problem map (or make a jsfiddle that exhibits the problem)?  Or a link or encrypted id for your table that is being used in the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like you have set up [your FusionTable map](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?snapid=S765811535r) to use the icons defined in that column.

You have to use the FusionTables User Interface to configure the map to use those icons.  Click on the "Configure styles" link and follow the instructions to assign icons to markers from a column (Points:Marker Icon:Column).

[See this entry in the "help"](http://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/185991/?&)